# Splash Screen using jquery will not show on Internet Explorer 11 works in chrome/Edge

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, splash-screen

I am creating a splash screen that simply shows the users a stock image with a dark overlay behind it. Then on top of the image is a "pop up" box with a dialog prompting user to click the get start button.

This script works fine on chrome and edge but IE 11 just shows the overlay and the image. I am not seeing the welcome box on IE 11. This does work on Chrome and Edge perfectly.

```
<div id="overlay">
        <div id="overlay-content">
            <img class="centeredImage" src="../../Images/Layout/splashTwo.jpg" alt="Welcome Screen" />

            <div id="welcomeBox">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Welcome to Tyler Launcher</h2>
                    <h6>Inside Tyler Launcher you will</h6>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Build your own launch pad with vital programs</li>
                        <li>Personalize your pages with critical tools, emails and calendars</li>
                        <li>Analyze and review metrics important to you</li>
                        <li>Learn new tool and tricks to help frow your knowledge and efficiency</li>
                    </ul>
                    <h5>To being, let's start personalizing your default tiles.</h5>
                </div>
                <div id="welcomeButton">
                    <a id="getStarted" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Let's get Personal</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

SplashScreen: function () {
      $.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position", "absolute");
        this.css("top", Math.max(0, (
          ($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) +
           $(window).scrollTop()) + "px"
        );
        this.css("left", Math.max(0, (
          ($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) +
           $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"
        );
        return this;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$("#overlay").show();
        $(this).children('#overLay').show();



    });
    //Event to launch personal user options   
    $('#getStarted').click(function () {

        //Do something after button is clicked
        alert('This will be the personalized launch options for the user');

        //Close all splash screen content
        $("#overlay").hide();

    });

},
```

**Here is the css**

```
#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1.0;
    z-index:2;
}

#overlay-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;

}

.centeredImage {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

}

#welcomeBox {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cce6ff;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Noted: This code seems to work fine on the latest chrome and edge browsers.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex

Comment: Ahh looks like flex is partially supported for IE 11, possibly why I get partially what I want on IE .

Comment: exactly my point ;)

Comment: I've commented out anything related to flex,flex-shrink, justify-content and align items. Still no success, I can see the the background overlay and the stock image but the welcome box is still not showing even after clearing my cache.

Comment: Also since ive commented out those related styles, it does not show on chrome, Suggested stylings to have those items show in the correct order?